# Excel VBA: Create hierarchical list in form of "I-1, I-2, II-1, II-2" dynamically based on input

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a dynamic numbered list in the format of column "I", which will be generated by the values in B1 and B2: [image: example picture]

The roman and the arabic numbers should be dynamic based on cell values in B1 and B2. I already tried VBA, but I could not work out the for loops to generate the correct result. Also I´m not sure how to implement the roman numbers.
Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Roman_Number As Integer
Dim Arabic_Number As Integer

Roman_Number = Range("B1").Value
Arabic_Number = Range("B2").Value

For i = 0 To (Roman_Number - 1)
    Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = "I" & "-" & (i + 1)
    Next i 

End Sub
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a worksheet function to generate roman numbers and you will need nested loops so the code should look like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim Roman_Number As Integer
    Dim Arabic_Number As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    Roman_Number = Range("B1").Value
    Arabic_Number = Range("B2").Value
    
    row = 1
    
    For i = 1 To Roman_Number
        For j = 1 To Arabic_Number
            Cells(row, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Roman(i) & "-" & j
            row = row + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Integer is OK as long as the numbers aren't too large.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you have got Roman and Arabic mixed up? Anyways, if you are fine with formula instead:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=TOCOL(ROMAN(SEQUENCE(B1))&"-"&SEQUENCE(1,B2))
```

Comment: Brilliant solution :-)  (just a side note: Excel 365 current channel is necessary due to `TOCOL`)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use a formula if you have Excel 365:

```
=LET(cntArabic,B2,
     cntRoman,B1,
     s,SEQUENCE(cntArabic*cntRoman),
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(s),1,LAMBDA(r,c,
         ROMAN(ROUNDUP(r/cntRoman,0)) & "-" & 
         IF(MOD(r,cntRoman)=0,cntRoman,MOD(r,cntRoman))  
     )))
```